# Javascript automatic save input txt value to div

Tags: javascript, function, text, input

I looking for some help to solve my problem.

I need to write JS function witch automatically save value of input field into div (with no button).

When value ends with "enter" key it save it to div, clear input field and set cursor in it again to put another value.

If anybody understood my english I would be appreciate for some tips:)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any code for this issue?

Comment: Unfortune I don't know how to "bite" this problem. I know how to add value to div with onclick button and clear it but how to set it when i finish filling field with text is all Greek to me. When I will come up with some code I write it here.

Comment: The problem here is that you need to provide the basics; an HTML layout and some attempt at the javascript to start. Everything you have asked for has answers already on this site and around the web. Make your question more specific to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example to get you started.

```js
const formElement = document.getElementById("form");
const inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
const outputElement = document.getElementById("output");

formElement.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {

  outputElement.append(inputElement.value);
  inputElement.value = "";

  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="input"></input>
</form>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for a tip I will work with that :) It looks really simply now.